# What's the meaning of ulimit -a output?

Tags: ulimit

What each of the values listed in the output of `ulimit -a` represents?

For example, what's the meaning of the following output (I've removed the obvious ones)?

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

core file size - maximum size of core file when a process core dumps

data seg size - maximum size of the process data segment, contains stuff like the heap

pending signals - number of signals allowed to be waiting while blocked

max locked memory - amount of memory that can be locked so it isn't paged out

max memory size - maximum memory in physical RAM

real-time priority - maximum 'nice' value for ordinary users

stack size - maximum memory for the stack

cpu time - maximum amount of cpu time (not real time) the process can use

virtual memory - basically the total memory the process can use